# How to restrict remote connections to internal connections only?

Tags: security, remote-access, teamviewer

A new security policy has been implemented at the company i work for meaning that we have to find a way of restricting all remote connections to be internal only. Problem is that 60% of users at the company use Teamviewer which although has a setting that can do what we need, as these users span 4 countries to change them all manually would be a logistical nightmare

Is there a GPO setting that can be changed?

Comment: You need a VPN solution or else a ton of public IP addresses and specific IP to interface NAT rules, etc. Look into a VPN solution such as IPSEC client VPN or SSL based, etc. Start doing some homework but let's see if you get other suggestions. You're going to have to enforce traffic in a manner such as block everything and start allowing only explicit things in (and out). Figure out what you need to block for the TeamViewer connections because that's the only way to prevent that if you allow outgoing Internet traffic without filtering rules, etc. Firewall and VPN solution time.

Comment: I'm sure there are PC level solutions on those which you control for the company that's connected to the network to disallow or only allow specific apps to be launched helping prevent the TV app from running on the machines at that level. If the only incoming connections you need to take care of are the clients with TV sessions, then maybe that would work,

Comment: If you company want to change policy, then they should consider spending money on an easily managed and configurable device to build network rules and such that has good support, etc. to help simplify this task. It would be money well spent if the data being protected is important to the business. If the data is breached one time, how much will that cost; more than a nice firewall appliance and/or VPN appliance with support, etc. Start giving them realistic ideas and do some research, call some vendors, do some demos, etc. Take your time and get best for your needs.

Comment: Surely all of this ^^^^^^^^ should be an answer lol... :)